# ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host for CentOS 6 systems

Tags: linux, sftp

I am trying to sftp to a site but it keeps disconnecting me with an error message "ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host". It only happens on CentOS 6 machines, so it's possibly related to having outdated packages. Maybe the host does not allow use of older protocols. I know CentOS 6 has reached EOF and the system is due for a replacement but I am hoping to get by for now.

I have tried updating to the latest packages for CentOS 6 but still fails. When I do `lsof -n | grep ssh | grep DEL`, I get the following:

```
sshd      13300    root  DEL       REG                0,4               36375 /dev/zero
sshd      13300    root  DEL       REG                0,4               36343 /dev/zero
```

Does this mean anything?

Will requesting to be whited listed in the /etc/hosts.allow help?

Comment: Did you try compiling an old version of `ssh` and using only that to connect to the Centos 6 system?

Comment: I am trying to connect to the remote host using SFTP. The remote host is rejecting connections from CentOS 6 systems. When I try connect to the remote host using CentOS 7/8, it works fine.

Comment: Then you'll need to compile a modern SSH on the old Centos 6 system, and use that.

Comment: Could also be the sshd configuration. Check if the configuration meets the current recommendations (especially regarding used ciphers). Running ssh with `-v` would also be helpful, as well as  sshd's log messages,